# Velocity - split string on Capital and insert underscore

Tags: maven, split, velocity

I am new to Velocity and am using to as as part of creating a maven archetype.
I need to split string that I get from a variable, ie  ${application-class-name}, on Capital letters (2nd onwards), and insert underscore, eg
HomeDetails => Home_Details
Is there a simple way of doing this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that velocity references are plain Java objects, on which you can call all public methods.

Also, note that depending on the version of Velocity that you use and on how it's configured, you *may* be able to use `-` in reference names, but that you should if possible avoid it.

You would typically do:

```
#set($originalApplicationClassName = 'HomeDetails')
#set($newApplicationClassName = $originalApplicationClassName.replaceAll("(?<!)([A-Z])", "_$1"))
```

where `(?<!)([A-Z])` is a regular expression starting with a *zero-width negative lookbehind* group (to skip the first capital).